# UIWebview and Printing

Tags: ios, swift, printing, uiwebview

I am trying to print the content in my webview that is made from a local html file and the webview it is set to fit the screen, the problem is that I want to print the content of the webview and it is printed on 2 piece of A4 sheets instead of scaling it a bit down to print on only one sheet of paper, is there anybody who knows how to scale it down to one page ?

My printing method:

```
@IBAction func printWebPage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) 
{
  let url = MainWebView.request?.URL
  let stringurl = url?.absoluteString

  let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
  let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)

  printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
  printInfo.jobName = url  

  pic!.printInfo = printInfo
  pic!.printFormatter = MainWebView.viewPrintFormatter()
  pic!.showsPageRange = false

  pic!.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```